# Assignment operator in C

Tags: c, language-lawyer, volatile, assignment-operator

```
volatile int lhs = 1;
int rhs = 2;
int x = 3;

x = lhs = rhs;
```

Does an assigment operator return the (typeof lhs)rhs ? or Does it return new, just read value of lhs ?
It is important to me since lhs is volatile and it can change between assigments.

I couldnt find the anwser at cpprefernce.

Comment: See [chained assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Chained_assignment).

Comment: I think the question here is, suppose `lhs` is a memory location that, no matter what you write to it, a read always returns 42.  Will `x` in the sample code end up containing 2 or 42?

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [assignment expressions and volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666916/assignment-expressions-and-volatile)

Comment: @jarmod: Why should we see that page; what does it tell us about the `volatile` issue in this question?

Comment: It is very bad practice to write an expression with 4 side effects that are dubiously sequenced in relation to each other.

Answer (score 8):

The C standard does not specify this whether `lhs` is read or not; it permits either behavior.

C 2018 6.5.16 specifies the assignment operators. Paragraph 3 says:

> … An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment,<sup>115)</sup> but is not an lvalue…

Footnote 115 says:

> The implementation is permitted to read the object to determine the value but is not required to, even when the object has volatile-qualified type.

Thus, the implementation is permitted to do either of:

- read the stored value of `lhs` (presumably after the side effect of updating it is complete) to determine the value of `lhs = rhs;`, or
- directly use the value resulting from converting `rhs` to the type of `lhs`.

Comment: that's what i wanted to hear. thanks